# Cake php redirect error [Can not modify header information]

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I'm new to CakePHP. I'm just testing how it works. I use other frameworks in PHP. Here in CakePHP 3.6 freshly installed. I'm following CakePHP's blog tutorial. My code is:

```
 $article = $this->Articles->newEntity();
            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                // Prior to 3.4.0 $this->request->data() was used.
                $article = $this->Articles->patchEntity($article, $this->request->getData());
                if ($this->Articles->save($article)) {
                    $this->Flash->success(__('Your article has been saved.'));
                   return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
                }
                else {
                    $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your article.'));
                }

            }
            $this->set('article', $article);
```

The problem is while redirecting to another action. When I comment line  `return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);` it works else it throws following error.

`Warning (512): Unable to emit headers. Headers sent in file=C:\Users\Dipti\blog\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\Debugger.php line=853 [CORE\src\Http\ResponseEmitter.php, line 48]
Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Users\Dipti\blog\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\Debugger.php:853) [CORE\src\Http\ResponseEmitter.php, line 148]`

Comment: I have found `ob_start();` as solution. But that is not a good for framework.

Comment: You need to fix errors in the order the occur in. Most likely the headers already sent error here is only the result of the previous message (because showing that on screen already constituted _output_.)

Answer (score 5):

In your appController change

```
$this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
```

to

```
$this->loadComponent('RequestHandler', [
    'enableBeforeRedirect' => false
]);
```

(I know, this is not a great answer. If I have time I will expand it)

Comment: It saved time and solved current problem. Thank you.